# How to download all folders and files from dropbox using CoreAPI

Tags: java, api, dropbox

I'm integrating DropBox into my program, but downloading all folders, subfolders, and files within all folders is becoming a hassle to figure out. I know how to list all the folders and files from the root directory and download each individually using the below code:

```
DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = null;

            try {
                listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/");
            } catch (DbxException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

However, how would I go about downloading a folder within a folder that a user had specified? My program creates an interface similar to the DropBox Android app interface, and the the metadata for the folders and file is downloaded and saved upon clicking. I'm having an issue creating the correct path. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that I just encountered with one of my projects.

You have the start to where you can list the files, so to add on to it we need to do a simple for each loop. It should look like this: **NOTE: this will only get the files**

```
  for (DbxEntry child : listing.children){
    mClient.getFile("/PATHTOFILE/" + child.name, null, new FileOutputStream(filePath + mPathSep + child.name));
              }
```

In order to get the folders, I would suggest modifying the above code by adding some if statements. The DbxEntry has a isFile/Folder method that you can use to determine if it is a file. Once it hits a file you can do a new

```
 for (DbxEntry child : listing.children){
      if(child.isFile())
        mClient.getFile("/PATHTOFILE/" + child.name, null, new FileOutputStream("PATHTONEWFILE" + child.name));

      else
       new File(path).mkdir(); 
                  }
```

With this information, you can probably achieve you end goal.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer this. I actually figured it out using a different process. The process I'm using this a tad more complex but it is because I created a GUI that had to remember the directories to go back and go forward, and also to upload to a certain directory. Thank you, however!